# MySQL: Select data between particular hours

Tags: mysql, date

### Question

I want to select all data(rows) which lie between 06:45 hrs and 07:15 hrs everyday for the months of October, November.

### Info

- Timestamp in the table is in the format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000'
- Every data recorded has both a start timestamp column ('starts_at') and an end timestamp column('ends_at')
- I use a convert_tz to convert from 'gmt' to 'us/eastern'.

### Query Used

```
    select *
    from
      table1
    where
      NOT(
      (hour(convert_tz(starts_at,'gmt','us/eastern')+minute(convert_tz(ends_at,'gmt','us/eastern'))) < 06.45 AND
      (hour(convert_tz(ends_at,'gmt','us/eastern'))+minute(convert_tz(ends_at,'gmt','us/eastern'))) > 07.15
      ) AND
      convert_tz(starts_at,'gmt','us/eastern') > '2015-10-01 00:00:00.000' AND
      convert_tz(ends_at,'gmt','us/eastern') < '2015-12-01 00:00:00.000'
    order by starts_at, ends_at
```

### Issue

With this query, I am getting data for the entire day (from 00 till 23 hrs) and not just the time period between which I want.

#### Edit 1:  As per @GordonLinoff's answer

Query,

```
select
   convert_tz(starts_at,'gmt','us/pacific') as Starts,
   convert_tz(ends_at,'gmt','us/pacific') as Ends
from
   table1
where
   (100 * hour(convert_tz(starts_at,'gmt','us/pacific'))+minute(convert_tz(starts_at,'gmt','us/pacific'))) >= 0645 AND
   (100 * hour(convert_tz(ends_at,'gmt','us/pacific'))+minute(convert_tz(ends_at,'gmt','us/pacific'))) <= 0715 AND
   convert_tz(starts_at,'gmt','us/pacific') > '2015-12-01 00:00:00.000' AND
   convert_tz(ends_at,'gmt','us/pacific') < '2015-12-20 00:00:00.000' 
order by starts_at, ends_at
```

And the response (sample of first few rows to only illustrate the issue of getting timestamps beyond the range)

`+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| Starts                  | Ends                    |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 2015-12-01 06:45:03.549 | 2015-12-01 06:45:35.003 |
| 2015-12-01 06:45:35.003 | 2015-12-01 06:47:00.203 |
| 2015-12-01 06:47:00.203 | 2015-12-01 06:54:11.615 |
| 2015-12-01 06:47:00.780 | 2015-12-01 06:47:40.860 |
| 2015-12-01 06:47:40.860 | 2015-12-01 06:48:52.103 |
| 2015-12-01 06:48:52.103 | 2015-12-01 06:51:33.925 |
| 2015-12-01 06:51:33.925 | 2015-12-01 06:52:34.543 |
| 2015-12-01 06:52:34.543 | 2015-12-01 07:00:00.000 |
| 2015-12-01 06:54:11.615 | 2015-12-01 06:59:59.074 |
| 2015-12-01 06:59:59.074 | 2015-12-01 07:14:59.074 |
| 2015-12-01 06:59:59.158 | 2015-12-01 07:14:59.158 |
| 2015-12-01 06:59:59.388 | 2015-12-01 07:14:59.388 |
| 2015-12-01 06:59:59.393 | 2015-12-01 07:14:59.393 |
| 2015-12-01 06:59:59.513 | 2015-12-01 07:14:59.513 |
| 2015-12-01 06:59:59.708 | 2015-12-01 07:14:59.708 |
| 2015-12-01 07:00:00.000 | 2015-12-01 07:15:00.000 |
| 2015-12-01 07:00:00.000 | 2015-12-01 07:15:00.000 |
| 2015-12-01 07:00:00.000 | 2015-12-01 07:15:00.000 |
| 2015-12-01 07:00:00.000 | 2015-12-01 07:15:00.000 |
| 2015-12-01 07:00:01.912 | 2015-12-01 07:14:59.471 |
| 2015-12-01 21:59:59.158 | 2015-12-02 00:59:59.158 |
| 2015-12-01 21:59:59.388 | 2015-12-02 06:59:59.388 |
| 2015-12-01 21:59:59.513 | 2015-12-02 06:59:59.513 |
| 2015-12-01 22:00:00.000 | 2015-12-02 01:00:00.000 |
| 2015-12-01 22:00:00.000 | 2015-12-02 01:00:00.000 |
| 2015-12-01 22:43:26.458 | 2015-12-02 05:13:23.365 |
| 2015-12-01 23:15:05.493 | 2015-12-02 05:08:38.585 |
| 2015-12-01 23:18:10.110 | 2015-12-02 05:09:29.648 |
| 2015-12-01 23:31:41.896 | 2015-12-02 00:10:16.796 |
| 2015-12-01 23:45:37.852 | 2015-12-02 00:19:22.301 |
| 2015-12-01 23:53:48.851 | 2015-12-02 00:17:20.538 |
| 2015-12-02 06:51:11.221 | 2015-12-02 06:51:16.456 |
| 2015-12-02 06:51:16.456 | 2015-12-02 07:01:19.435 |`

Only those timestamps in the range 2100 till 0045 keep repeating themselves across the entire dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract and convert your hours into minutes.

```
SELECT 
      * 
FROM
     table1
WHERE
      HOURS(starts_at) * 60 + MINUTES(starts_at) >= 405
  And HOURS(ends_at) * 60   + MINUTES(ends_at)   <= 435
order by
starts_at,ends_at
```

Comment: I deleted previous comment because I got the query to work! Thanks! Made a change: `(HOUR(convert_tz(starts_at,'gmt','us/central')) * 60 + MINUTE(convert_tz(starts_at,'gmt','us/central')) <= 405)` . Do not know why, but adding those extra brackets ensured that I did not get timestamps beyond my range.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
select *
from
  table1
where
  NOT(
  (time(convert_tz(starts_at,'gmt','us/eastern'))) < '06:45' AND
  (time(convert_tz(ends_at,'gmt','us/eastern'))) > '07:15'
  ) AND
  convert_tz(starts_at,'gmt','us/eastern') > '2015-10-01 00:00:00.000' AND
  convert_tz(ends_at,'gmt','us/eastern') < '2015-12-01 00:00:00.000'
order by starts_at, ends_at
```

Comment: Thanks! 
But using the 'time' function did not work for me. It again returned all values from 0000 hrs onward.

Answer (score 0):

`Hour` + `minute` is going to be a value between 0 (at midnight) and 82 (23 + 59).  In addition, a value cannot both be `< 6.45` and `> 7.15`.

There are several approaches to do what you want.  The following follows the gist of your approach:

```
  (100 * hour(convert_tz(starts_at,'gmt','us/eastern')+minute(convert_tz(ends_at,'gmt','us/eastern'))) >= 0645 AND
  (100 * hour(convert_tz(ends_at,'gmt','us/eastern'))+minute(convert_tz(ends_at,'gmt','us/eastern'))) <= 0715
  ) AND
```

Note there is no `NOT`.  This converts the hour minutes into a number of the form HHMM, which can be compared to a number.

Comment: Thanks ! Your info works except that it also gives me timestamps beyond the range I have selected. 

Note: only those timestamps from 2100 hrs till 0030 hrs (of next day) keep occurring beyond the range.. Otherwise, i only get those timestamps between 0645 and 0715.

Comment: @shriramks . . . You should edit your question with sample data and desired results.